# Near field probing on a large DUT

Tags: noise, emc, testing

I "inherited" a set of boards (it's an elevator controller) that have no 'explicit' EMC countermeasures except a single CM choke for the CAN bus. And, of course, now the whole thing need to be tested (as in, a 3m+ whole elevator carried into the shield room).

Most of the I/Os are digital 24V signals (from microswitches and similar automation devices), they have some current limiting resistors and TVS for protection; I'd expect that these resistor would at least help with radiated noise. Outputs however are plain BJTs.

I'm not exactly worried about conducted emissions; the whole thing is powered by a good 24V power supply and the motor VFD has it's own *huge* power filter, as recommended by the manufacturer; shielding the power cables to the motor will be the first thing at all (yes, they didn't even shielded the power cable to a 3kW motor driven by a VFD; and they expect to pass testing, too). Also there are China supplies for the lighting led strips but these are another issue.

My experience till now was with smallish machines and the main problem was radiated emission from cables (most of the time some MCU clock or similar). These I can handle even if I don't think I'll have enough time to respin the board if I need to add ferrites/capacitors to the circuit.

My doubt here is about the cables connecting the boards; there are wires *everywhere* included some very long cables (think about a bus running for the whole length for the call buttons and then to the car). 10m *unshielded* cables with 20+ wires inside.

I'm not experienced in machines so big but I expect these to pick up the MCU clocks at every board (about 75MHz with 6-7 boards) and radiate them around. At least grounding seems robust.

I have no CM current probe so my plan would be to run an H-field probe around the cables looking for stationary nodes and then trying to handle them (possibly with cable ferrites). I have an HZ530 set and in the past it worked well for similar issues but I've never used it in a board-to-board situation (also the high impedance contact probe only work up to 20VDC).

In short: I have board A (potentially leaking CM noise to the cable), a fat, long and complex cable from it attached to board B (and even that board could have issues).

Any suggestion for this kind of work? some useful tip?

Comment: Please write a specific question

Answer (score 1):

> I'm not experienced in machines so big but I expect these to pick up
> the MCU clocks at every board (about 75MHz with 6-7 boards) and
> radiate them around. At least grounding seems robust.

The cables could radiate. There are two options, either make the impedance higher on the PCB with a ferrite (or use a ferrite on the cable). Or short out the high frequency signals by letting them return to the source (the PCB) with a capacitor.

> have no CM current probe so my plan would be to run an H-field probe
> around the cables looking for stationary nodes and then trying to
> handle them (possibly with cable ferrite).

You can use a near field probe, and that will give you an *idea* of what the radiating sources are. But if you want the product to pass FCC, then it will also need to pass the far field test, and it's hard to predict how the near-field will affect the far field. So do a precompliance test to make sure you are passing, bring ferrite for cable radiation, if it passes without, then you have a lower BOM cost. You may have to redesign the PCB, it's always good to put not loaded caps and ferrites on cables that could be suspected radiators.

Comment: More or less my experiences.I'd need to study the gerbers, maybe there's a way to add capacitors to ground on the current board. In my previous job we had a somewhat compulsive ferrite policy on the I/O so we used tons of BLM around (and then failed the normal mode conducted due to insufficient choking ^_^;)